# UIButton's Selected State not working in iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

I am using Xcode 5's storyboarding to create an application, iOS SDK 7.0.

I dragged a button to the View. I want my button to display "A" by Default. Below are the button properties:
Type: System, State Config: Default, Title: Plain

I want my button to display "B" in selected state. So, the button properties that changed:
State Config: Selected

In the Button's Attribute inspector, under the Control, there is a property called Selected.
If I check Selected, instead of displaying "B", it just highlights like a marker over A, i.e, no character is seen.

I ran it in XCODE. WHen the button is not selected "A" is displayed as expected but when I select the button, instead of displaying B, the text portion of the button is highlighted with light blue color. Also, I never selected the Highlighted Content under the Control.

How can this be resolved, so that I can display the state correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the **title** of the button to 'B' while you have **State Config set to Selected** in your storyboard.  Then you need to connect an action to the button's Touch Up Inside event.  Inside of that action, toggle the button's `selected` property.

When you check 'Selected' under the Attributes Inspector, you are just setting the button's initial selected state to YES.  XCode also shows you what the button would look like in that state.

Comment: Worth noting also that you have Type: Custom selected as none of this makes a difference otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who set the button title by code, I found on iOS 7.1, you need to explicitly set title for various button states, while on iOS 7.0, setting title for UIControlStateNormal will also do for other button states.

```
// works on 7.0
[self.ibActionButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Register", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// works on 7.1
[self.ibActionButton setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Register", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateDisabled];
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that this is a bug in XCODE 5, that is, when we check the selected property under Control for the button, it doesn't show the selected state on the Button. It works in the simulator we run the application. We would need to do a target-action for the button and toggle the selected state as below

```
 - (IBAction)flipButton:(UIButton *)sender {
      sender.selected=!sender.isSelected;
   }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the button change to the selected value all by itself?