# Why is HighlightedImage ignored

Tags: ios, uibutton, state

I have a button, in normal state it is supposed to look like this:

[image]

in highlighted state it's supposed to look like this:

[image]

in selected state its supposed to look like this:
[image]

now state normal, and state selected seem to work just fine.

except that in state  highlighted, the code seems to ignore my request for the highlighted provided image, and makes it look like this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
     self.iconButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [self.iconButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
     [self.view addSubview:self.iconButton];
     [self.iconButton addTarget:self selector:@selector(buttonClicked:) forEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.iconButton.adjustsImageWhenDisabled = YES;
    self.iconButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;

    [self.iconButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.iconButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_pressed"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.iconButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check_v"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

**my question is: how do i make the code recognize my requested image, or alternatively how do i just simply provide the color for the button to color my "highlighted" state ?**

Comment: I think you can find what you need by reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198858/uibuttons-selected-state-not-working-in-ios7

Comment: This does not help, this button is created programmatically, not via interface builder

Comment: @Stavash any more suggestions ?

Comment: Can you somehow share the problemtic storyboard? Maybe a demo project?

Comment: This button is created in code, i did not put it in a storyboard

Comment: How are you initializing it and adding it to the view heirarchy? Can you add some more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.iconButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

This setting makes the system adapt the highlighted image automatically, which is not what you want (you want to use your own image). Try setting it to NO, and see if it improves the situation.

Comment: I changed this setting to NO -> it did change something, but i did not get the result i wanted. Now the highlighted version of the button is the same as the normal version

Comment: your answer is partially correct, indeed setting the state to NO was required. However, my button, from selected state (and that is my fault for not mentioning that the initial state of the button was "selected") , now on pressing returned to normal state, instead of highlighted state like i wanted. So I needed to put a boolean to check if i am in selected state, then on press i need to set the normal image to the highlighted one, and all worked well.