# UIButton not changing on selected state

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to make a simple UIButton that changes background image every time it is clicked. This is the code:

```
UIButton *likeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[likeButton addTarget:self
               action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-like-grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-dislike-color.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

.

```
- (IBAction)likeButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (sender.isSelected) {
        [sender setSelected:NO];
        NSLog(@"not selected");
    } else {
        [sender setSelected:YES];
        NSLog(@"selected");
    }
}
```

Apparently it gets selected the first time, and the button turns from grey to color. However, it then does not turn back to grey after it has been clicked a second time. The `NSLog` shows the correct code, so the problem must be on the `[sender setSelected: ]` line. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"in nil");
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

mainDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

cell.textLabel.text = @"Text";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18];

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [mainDelegate.imagesDescription objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

        } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [mainDelegate.imagesURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

            SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
            [manager downloadWithURL:url
                                  options:0
                                 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize, long long expectedSize) {

                                 }
                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished) {

                                    if (image && finished) {
                                        cell.imageView.image = image;
                                    }
                                }
             ];

            UIButton *likeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [likeButton addTarget:self
                           action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-like-grey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-dislike-color.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

            likeButton.frame = CGRectMake(215, 60, 40, 40);
            likeButton.layer.borderWidth = 0;
            cell.textLabel.text = @"";

            [cell addSubview:likeButton];


        } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {

            NSString *location = [mainDelegate.imagesLocation objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
            cell.textLabel.text = location;

            UILabel *labelRight = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 100)];
            labelRight.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;

            labelRight.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [mainDelegate.imagesLikes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section], @"Likes"];
            cell.accessoryView = labelRight;
        }

return cell;

}
```

Comment: maybe you should set correct image to UIControlStateHighlighted state when button is pressed

Comment: @0Silencer I don't understand what does ``UIControlStateHighlighted`` has to do with ``UIControlStateSelected``

Comment: Your button has a title? If not check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198858/uibuttons-selected-state-not-working-in-ios7

Comment: @SirKuryaki - No, it does not have a title. However I am not using storyboards at this moment because the UIButton is shown programmatically on certain cells from a UITableView. So I think that answer does not affect me. Still, I have tried adding a title and nothing.

Comment: I've checked the same code and it's working. Can you try with a button outside the tableview?

Comment: @SirKuryaki - You are right. I think the problem must come from the fact that it is not the only button. Every section in the tableview has the same button.

Comment: for switching button state only sender.selected=!sender.selected; is enough. no need to write if else condition.

Comment: paste your code of the method cellForRowAtIndexPath. Where are you doing the alloc?

Comment: You're allocating a new button on every call of cellForRowAtIndexPath. You have to keep what rows have been selected. You only have one button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a subview for your like button every time a cell gets dequeued, rather than just updating button's state. In this case a good practice is to subclass the UITableViewCell class and init it there, updating button's state from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. 
Though this will require you to store button states elsewhere as a datasource (and to update them in your `likeButtonPressed:` method).

Comment: That is a nice approach. Thanks.